# Read and write strings and integers to binary file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary

I am trying to write, then read the following data to a binary file but keep getting the wrong output.

```
str_cetag = 'AIMIDB';
cel_num = 00089;
acq_date = 20150422110459;

% Open and write to file
fid = fopen('BFile.bin','w');
fwrite(fid,str_cetag);
fwrite(fid,cel_num);
fwrite(fid,acq_date);
fclose(fid);

% Open and read from file
fid = fopen('BFile.bin','r');
fread(fid,6,'uint8=>char')';
fread(fid,5,'uint8=>double')';
fread(fid,14,'uint8=>double')';
fclose(fid);

% Output
ans = 0
ans = AIMIDB
ans = 89   255   127
ans = []
ans = 0
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the bin file for reproducibility?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary file I am creating for the purpose of this example...

Comment: okay what does a bin or your bin usually look like? A stream of binary numbers?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is be able to write integers and strings to a text file, then read them back. This exercise is in support of learning binary file I/O for a reader that I need to work on. So, to answer your question, the file should be a stream of 1's and 0's.

Comment: @krisdestruction, the bin file is completely reproduceable by the code that greg has provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your output, you may notice that `str_cetag` and `cel_num` are written and read correctly.  The problem is that `acq_date` is far too large to be stored as an 8 bit unsigned integer, which is the default for `fwrite`.

This works correctly:

```
str_cetag = 'AIMIDB';
cel_num = 89;
acq_date = 20150422110459;

% Open and write to file
fid = fopen('BFile.bin','w');
fwrite(fid,str_cetag);
fwrite(fid,cel_num,'uint8');
fwrite(fid,acq_date,'uint64');
fclose(fid);

% Open and read from file
fid = fopen('BFile.bin','r');
fread(fid,6,'uint8=>char')'
fread(fid,1,'uint8')'
fread(fid,'uint64')'
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Yes... I read back what I write, but if I were to do this in an algorithm, how would I specify to read the size of cel_num? Right now you have it specified as 1, whereas it's 5 digits...

Comment: The number of decimal digits does not matter.  It is stored as a single uint8.

Comment: So when I write fread(fid,'uint8=>char') for str_cetag, or even fread(fid,'uint8') for cel_num, why don't those commands work?

Comment: If you do not specify a number of bytes to read, then `fread` defaults to reading the entire remainder of the file.  This is why you were getting an empty array for `acq_date` in your original code.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about the whole size argument. I just tried the following and got the correct output:

fread(fid,6,'uint8=>char')'

fread(fid,1,'uint8')'

fread(fid,14,'uint64')'